# Self-modifying code in commercial games for the (S)NES, Gameboy, Genesis/MD, PC Engine, Atari, etc

Tags: nes, snes, sega-genesis

I'm curious if there are any extant examples of commercial games for classic consoles (let's say, pre-32-bit era here) which make uses of self-modifying code. As far as I know, all the systems I've listed are capable of executing from RAM. I know this for a fact, in the case of the Gameboy, and I can't conceive of anything which would limit the others from doing so.

Comment: This isn't intentional, but there's an exploit in Mario that you can use to execute code in memory which sends you to the end credits: https://hackaday.com/2015/01/22/reprogramming-super-mario-world-from-inside-the-game/

Comment: the consoles are able to execute code from RAM, but they usually have not a lot of RAM (I'm talking about the consoles with cartridges), so I think it's VERY rare if someone uses the small RAM used for data to store code just to perform SMC (maybe to gain performance in some situations). On _computers_ on the other hand it happened all the time

Comment: "as far as I know, all the systems I've listed are capable of executing from RAM": you have to be more specific when you're saying that Atari is a system. Which one is it? VCS 2600, XL, ST, Jaguar ?

Comment: I’ll bet there’s at least one example for the Atari Lynx: that machine treats its cartridges strictly as serial secondary store, being able to execute *only* from its 64kb of RAM.

Comment: @llama Yeah, that exploit (or an analogue on Gameboy, I think) was what gave me the idea for this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know about one Atari 8bit game called [Robbo](https://www.mobygames.com/game/robbo). There are [source codes published](http://sources.pigwa.net/files/gry/robbo.zip) where in file R1.ASM you can see:

```
     LDA LMVT,X
     STA JMP1+1
     LDA LMVT+4,X
     STA JMP1+2
JMP1 JMP *

LMVT DTA L(UP_)
     DTA L(DW_)
     DTA L(LT_)
     DTA L(RT_)

     DTA H(UP_)
     DTA H(DW_)
     DTA H(LT_)
     DTA H(RT_)
```

LDA gets address from table indexed by X register, STA stores this address in JMP instruction (after OPCODE, so JMP1+1). JMP jumps to different locations depending on value in X register.
I think this is quite typical situation for self modifying code - modify only parameters of instruction not whole instruction.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but Atari 8 bit is a computer (400XL, 800XL) not a console right? Self-modifying code is very common in computer games, to avoid indirect calls/reads for instance. I know a ton of examples on Amiga (68000): Ex: Dune, Red Zone... and Oric (6502) but those aren't consoles.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is a console too; see the XEGS, which comes from the Commodore C64GS / Amstrad GX4000 school of thought.

Comment: Any reason not to use the RTS trick here? It would save 4 bytes and not take more time.

Comment: @Wilson Or store the address in zero-page RAM and `JMP (addr)`.

Comment: @fadden To store address in zero-page RAM you have to know which of 4 addresses to store there (UP_, DW_, LT_, RT_). To avoid SMC I would rather write something like this: `DEX; BMI UP_; BEQ DW_; DEX; BEQ LT_; JMP RT_`

Comment: @Wilson: Better yet, if one can spare a couple byte of RAM "full time", place jump targets so they're all in the same page, and have the upper byte of a pair hold the MSB of that page address, so only the lower byte will need to be updated.  Even if there's only enough room in that page for a JMP, that would still be faster than having to use an extra load/store for the upper page address.

Answer (score 11):

I rarely had occasion to use self-modifying code. Doing that had a lot of overhead both in ROM space and RAM space, and I rarely saw an occasion where it would be worth it. I did do it on the IBM PC, where I had bunches of block moves to do that were not contiguous, and doing so eliminated looping overhead during a critical time, at the expense of some RAM.

I did, however, use a variant for copy protection.  We ROM programmers were always in an arms race with people who cracked games. Usually, copy protection was bolted on after-the-fact by adding code that had no purpose but copy protection... typically a loop that wrote garbage into the ROM area (having no effect on ROM but destroying a RAM copy). It was easy enough for the crackers to disassemble the code and unbolt them.

On the other hand, games have many tables of gameplay parameters. Some were binary:  The robots do not shoot on level 1, but do on level 3. If there were 30 levels, that was 30 bytes *per parameter* unless you wanted to do a binary unpack.  ROM space was tight.

So I would store 3 binary tables in the same byte array: in bits 0, 6 and 7, and other values in bits 1-5.   To get to bit 0, I did

```
 ROR ($TABLE_REF),Y
```

And the value would pop into the carry flag. (Y has the level number, loaded earlier. table_ref is a zero page location preloaded with the table location). For bits 6 and 7, I would ASL - bit 7 drops into carry and bit 6 drops into sign.

This operation writes the shifted value back to RAM.  That has no effect on ROM. But in a RAM copy,  **it corrupts the gameplay table**. Playability is ruined: *The robots would never shoot*.

By using only a 2-byte instruction, the cracker couldn't just replace it with a 3-byte JSR to a replacement subroutine.  It required rewriting that section of the code.

Comment: That's a brilliant technique! It would be interesting to know for which particular systems you did programming that used this.

Answer (score 9):

RAM and ROM are reachable by the CPU for execution, so most consoles can execute code from RAM.

The consoles using cartridges usually don't have a lot of RAM, so I think it's VERY rare if someone uses the small RAM used for data to store code just to perform self-modifying code.

On computers on the other hand it happened all the time, just because

1. it's sometimes easier than creating a table
2. it saves cycles and an indirection.

A CD console like the Amiga CD32 is a console but cannot run the code from CD obviously, so it *has* to load it into its 2MB RAM.

Same can be said for the Commodore CDTV, an earlier version, less powerful, which inherited a lot of Amiga games too.

Since those 2 consoles inherited a lot of Amiga games with very little adaptation, and some amiga games use self-modifying code, you can say that those consoles can use self-modifying code.

The CD32 console can also run CDTV titles. The fact that the processor is a 680EC20 could cause issues, so when detecting a CDTV title, the CD32 console turns the caches off, to handle CPU-dependent issues such as CPU-busy loops and cache issues (i.e. self-modifying code).

It's difficult to find an example of a real game that used self-modifying code on an official CD32 game but I found one: [Zool CD32](http://hol.abime.net/1635)

Disassembling the executable, we found several occurrences of this instruction in the code, (setting a label plus 2 is fishy enough and often a sign of self-modifying code):

```
MOVE.L  #LAB_0411,LAB_0404+2    ;00cefe: 23fc0000b2fa0000abd6
```

now at `LAB_0404` we find:

```
LAB_0404:
    JSR LAB_0868        ;00abd4: 4eb90001538c
    CLR.L   LAB_002F+2      ;00abda: 42b9000004ea
```

So the code changes the jump address depending on the situation (without flushing the caches afterwards). The 68020 instruction cache isn't big enough for this to be a (visible) issue.

---

Another completely unrelated example is the [Pengo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pengo_(video_game)) arcade video game. I reverse engineered the set 1 back in 2010 quite extensively, and browsing my notes I came across this piece of Z80 code:

```
;; install a modifiable routine in $8C24 (self-modifying code used
;; for maze path drawing)
    
2DB6: 06 85         ld   b,$0D
2DB8: 11 11 2E      ld   de,$2E39
2DBB: 21 24 8C      ld   hl,$8C24
2DBE: 1A            ld   a,(de)
2DBF: 77            ld   (hl),a
2DC0: 13            inc  de
2DC1: 23            inc  hl
2DC2: 10 7A         djnz $2DBE
```

As we can see, the game installs some code into `$8C24` which is in RAM (as opposed to the lower half like the above code which is in ROM). The code is installed in RAM so self-modifying code will work (this is a maze drawing algorithm, something quite complex to code in Z80 so if they had something working which used self-modifying code, so be it, they're going to use it)

Part of the code using this small smc routine:

```
    ;; those routines below use a self-modifying code technique to
    ;; change opcode and op value (bit & res and value)
    ;; 30CA tests if way is clear
    ;; 30D2 clears bits to mark that way is clear
    ;;
    ;; this kind of technique is used in tree scan recursive algorithms

    ;; returns z if way is clear, nz if not
is_way_clear_30CA
    : 16 CE         ld   d,$46  ; z80 operand mask
30CC: 18 8E         jr   $30D4
    ;; 30CE is not used
30CE: 16 EE         ld   d,$C6  ; z80 operand mask
30D0: 18 8A         jr   $30D4
    
set_way_clear_30D2
     16 86         ld   d,$86   ; z80 operand mask
30D4: 21 AF 8C      ld   hl,maze_hole_wall_bit_table_8C27
30D7: 79            ld   a,c
30D8: 2F            cpl
30D9: E6 07         and  $07
30DB: 07            rlca
30DC: 07            rlca
30DD: 07            rlca
30DE: B2            or   d
30DF: 32 0D A4      ld   ($8C25),a ; change operand of the bit/res opcode
30E2: 16 88         ld   d,$00
30E4: 58            ld   e,b
30E5: 19            add  hl,de
30E6: C3 0C A4      jp   $8C24  ; calls self-modifying code bit/res test routine!!
```

Last quick example, in the MAME source code (phoenix driver) I found this comment:

> as part of the protection, Survival (1982) executes code from $43a4

(address `$43A4` is in RAM, so game loads some code there so it's not directly visible in ROM)

Comment: `The consoles using cartridges usually don't not a lot of RAM, so I think it's VERY rare if someone uses the small RAM [...] to perform self-modifying code.` Doesn't have to be VERY rare. In many cases, just a very small routine that can be speeded up significantly with self-modifying code could be used. And since the RAm is here anyway - even when the game doesn't need all of it for it's internal state, it might as well be used for other uses.

Answer (score 7):

The NES game *Gimmick!* uses self modifying code as part of its anti-piracy check failure response. 96 bytes are decrypted while being copied from ROM to RAM and then jumped to. This is to hide a routine that halts the game and displays the message `BLACK HOLE` when certain conditions are met.

https://tcrf.net/Notes:Gimmick!

Answer (score 4):

(This is slightly off-topic, but related.)

The 65816 CPU has a pair of block move instructions, `MVN` and `MVP`, which allow you to copy up to 64KiB from one 24-bit address to another.  The instructions work like this:

```
ldx #{16-bit source address}
ldy #{16-bit destination address}
lda #{16-bit count - 1}
mvn src_bank, dest_bank
```

(The "bank" is the high 8 bits of the 24-bit address.)

The tricky part is the instruction itself, because part of the address is embedded in it.  If you happen to know the bank addresses at assembly time (e.g. you know source and destination are both in bank 0) you're fine, but in the general case you're *required* to use self-modifying code.

If you want to use these instructions from ROM code, you have to set up a move instruction somewhere in RAM and call it.  If your code is reentrant (due to interrupts) you can't simply use a fixed location.  IIRC the Apple IIgs ROM pushed the instruction onto the stack and called it there.